# Is there an easy way to see your "moderation score"?

Tags: discussion, election

I've been around this site long enough to *think* about *maybe possibly kinda* sometime in the next year or so, throw my name in for a moderator election. However at the moment I know I need to do a lot of work to improve my standing in the community and establish a good track record of performance and involvement. I would probably score about a 4/40 at the moment, and while I read/visit the site regularly, I haven't been a regular contributor aside from commenting on things.

So with the goal of improvement in mind, is there a way to easily see a checklist or similar view of which moderation badges you still need and what your score would be? Obviously it's doable with just a spreadsheet or something, but if there's an easier way, I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Part of what got me curious was checking the nomination form to see if it had that snapshot, but oddly it isn't there.

Answer (score 12):

[This SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/834092/candidate-score-in-an-election) calculates the candidate score for one or more users, breaking the results down by category (reputation, moderation badges, etc).  Your current score is actually *slightly* higher than what you predicted, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was also wondering how the score is generated. but can someone edit that query? It bugs me that 'Civic Duty' isn't on a new line in the list of mod badges!

Comment: @dwizum SEDE queries on SEDE behave differently from posts on Q&A sites.  I think if you edit it you get your own copy.  (It'll be linked on your profile there.)  I don't know if anybody other than the author can make direct edits.